# How to get the hashtags from Notes App? Python AppleScript

Tags: python, applescript

Example code that works with unformatted hashtags but not formatted hashtags:

```
from applescript import AppleScript

def get_notes_with_hashtags(folder, tag):
    script = AppleScript('tell application "Notes" to get id of every note in folder "' + folder + '" whose body contains "' + tag + '"')
    return script.run()
```

in NotesApp the formatted hashtags turn yellow and unformatted hashtags appear as `text`.

When getting results back for formatted hashtags, the result will return with an empty array.

Comment: Your explanation is fuzzy to me but perhaps what is happening is that the formatted text in the `body` has html tags and thus don't match the *whose* filter.

Comment: @Mockman for example if the note was the following with a formatted hashtag:

Title
Body
#tag

the html returned would look like this:

`<div><h1>Title</h1></div>
<div><br></div>
<div>Body<br></div>
<div><br></div>`

if you use plaintext request through AppleScript, it will look like the following:
`Title
Body
`

the example code i wrote above will return []... it's obviously wrong but I don't know anyway to access the formatted tag...

Comment: I'm using an old version of Notes that doesn't have #tags so I can only guess here. When you get the body of a note with a tag, what does it look like? If I write a tag and then format it, the line will look like this: `<div><b><font color=\"#FF619E\"><h1>#test</h1></font></b><b><h1><br></h1></b></div>`. If direct *tag* support hasn't been added to the applescript dictionary, then perhaps something like this might work: `id of notes whose body contains "<h1>#test</h1>"`.

Comment: @Mockman if the tag is in the title then it returns this body: `<div><h1>Title </h1><br><h1><br></h1></div>
<div>Body</div>`

I also tried your solution and it didn't work :(

I think you might be right about applescript not supporting tags which is unfortunate because I wanted the user to retain the ability of searching through their Note Apps with tags.

Comment: That's disappointing to hear. I wish apple would spend even a few minutes a year to make applescript usable with new features.